# Getting SelectField to populate with all choices and saved DB value selected on Edit form

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, wtforms, starlette

I am trying to pull the database data into the EditTicketForm with the SelectField drop down list populated with all of the valid choices and the saved value selected.

forms > ticket.py

```
class CreateTicketForm(StarletteForm):
...
    category_id = SelectField(
        'Category',
        coerce=int,
        validators=[DataRequired('Category Required')],
    )

class EditTicketForm(CreateTicketForm):
    pass
```

models > ticket.py

```
class Ticket(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tickets'
...
    category_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey("ticket_categories.id"),
        nullable=True)
    
    category: Mapped['TicketCategory'] = relationship(
        'TicketCategory',
        back_populates='ticket'
    )
```

The CreateTicketForm correctly builds the Category drop down and the category_id, along with the rest of the form data, is correctly saved into the database.

[How the CreateTicketForm is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENn5o.png)

The EditTicketForm will build without errors, with the rest of the form data correctly displayed.  However the Category drop down is not populated with the valid choices or with the saved value.

[How the EditTicketForm is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOA95.png)

Here is the code within the `@router.get`

```
form.title.data = ticket.title
form.body.data = ticket.body
form.category_id.choices = [(category.id, category.name) for category in ticketCategory]
form.category_id.data = ticket.category_id

form = EditTicketForm(
    request=request,
    title=ticket.title,
    body=ticket.body,
    category_id=ticket.category_id)
```